# How can I automatically answer yes in python?

Tags: python, debian, apt

Say I have a script that runs `apt upgrade -y` later on I'll need to manually answer these questions for different packages. How can I automatically do that?

Setting up virtualbox-guest-x11 (5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...

```
Configuration file '/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98vboxadd-xclient'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** 98vboxadd-xclient (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?  conffile prompt detected: /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98vboxadd-xclient /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98vboxadd-xclient.dpkg-new
```

My script is able to detect the confile prompt but how should I go about  answering yes automatically?

by using python-apt api I am able to detect the prompt via this funtion

```
def conffile(self, current, new):
    print " conffile prompt detected: %s %s" % (current, new)

    """(Abstract) Called when a conffile question from dpkg is detected."""
```

Comment: Why Python specifically? [Is there a way to force "Yes" to any prompts when installing from apt-get (from a bash script)?](//askubuntu.com/q/805067) tells me that `apt-get -y upgrade` should not prompt you at all.

Comment: Also there is the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable.

Comment: It is imperative that I do it in python.

Comment: Then at least show us your Python code used to run the command, so we can help correct it.

Comment: OK, just a moment

Comment: Next, have you looked at the [Python API](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/) yet? I'm sure it supports running an upgrade.

Comment: I have and that's my second option. I managed to detect the prompt but i just need to find a way to say yes.

Comment: That's not really enough to help us understand what you are doing. So you are already using `python-apt`? How is `conffile` hooked in?

Comment: Using the install progress base class: https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.progress.base.html#installprogress

Comment: @answerSeeker: please do *include that in your question*. There was no indication that you were using `python-apt` at the start, so people can assume that you were using `subprocess` instead. Don't leave us guessing or making assumptions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only thing left to do is find a way to send in "Y" or "Yes", then simulate an enter key.

Comment: @answerSeeker: perhaps, but by not making it clear what your setup is, you don't attract the experts in Debian's APT framework either. Only now that you revealed in the comments that you are using `Python-APT`, did you get an answer. You could have made this easier for everyone by stating this up front. And it looks like the answer lies *somewhere else* by configuring `apt` to not ask for confirmation in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who were lost like me, the answer is:

```
import apt_pkg

apt_pkg.init_config()
apt_pkg.config.set("DPkg::Options::", "--force-confnew")
```

This will make apt automatically accept new config files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `yes` command:

```
yes Y | apt ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since (per comment under the question) you're using [Python-APT](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/contents.html), the first way that comes to mind is using the [Configuration](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html#configuration-and-command-line-parsing) class to set `conf['APT::Get::Assume-Yes'] = True`.

Comment: I tried it like this: `conf = apt_pkg.config()
        conf['APT::Get::Assume-Yes'] = True` I ended up getting `apt_pkg.Configuration, object is not callable`

Comment: That would likely be because apt_pkg.config is already an instance. The very paragraph mentioning it also says you don't need another instance. Also, I haven't tested it so it's possible the True should be a string or something.