# How can I mark a specific conffile for overwriting using Python APT?

Tags: python, linux, apt

I'm using the [Python APT wrapper library](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/) to write an interactive APT interface. I want to handle the case when APT prompts if to overwrite or keep a config file during *apt-upgrade*.

This corresponds to the following user interaction in command-line APT:

```
Configuration file '/var/usr/myconf.cfg'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** myconf.cfg (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? Y
Installing new version of config file var/usr/myconf.cfg ...
Status change
```

I've found that *apt.progress.base.InstallProgress* has a callback function *conffile* which is called when APT prompts if to overwrite.

It has the following signature:

```
def conffile(self, current, new):
    """(Abstract) Called when a conffile question from dpkg is detected."""
```

Parameters *current* and *new* are the two filepaths involved. How can I use Python APT to mark the conffile for overwrite or keep programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python APT library does not seem to offer any way of resolving this. I ended up writing `Dpkg::Options { "–force-confnew"; }` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local` which always overwrites old conf files with new ones; I couldn't spend time extending the library.

One possible solution to get more user interaction would be to execute a manual dry run with the apt-command and parse all the conffile conflicts from the console output. Then one could prompt the user for a solution for all conf files and write
`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local` appropriately + call upgrade from the Python APT library.

Update: answerSeeker figured out a way to set these options programatically - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316879/how-can-i-automatically-answer-yes-in-python).

Comment: I asked the very same question and found the answer myself. The apt library does offer a way to do this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316879/how-can-i-automatically-answer-yes-in-python

Comment: Yeah the only bad thing is that you can't handle each overwrite question individually - since there is already a conffile callback one would expect to be able to mark each individual file as overwrite or keep.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought you wanted it to treat them automatically. `apt_pkg.config.set("DPkg::Options::", "--force-confnew")` to overrite new conffiles and `apt_pkg.config.set("DPkg::Options::", "--force-confold")` to keep old ones.

Comment: Yeah the automatic handling ended up my fallback solution. Originally I wanted to handle each case individually and expected to be able to do that because of the conffile callback- didn't emphasize that in my question though, so you're right about beeing confused. Good to know that there's a programmatic way of setting the automatic handling though.